# Keep content within Twitter Bootstrap Panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble keeping an `<object>` (a Twitch.tv Video) within a bootstrap panel. I cannot just set a "width" as this will change if the screen is resized, I would prefer to keep the content responsive just like the panels.

Also I had no luck using `position` either. It throws the layout off.

Here is a **[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PwS4S/)**

Note, you have to make sure the View is stretched out to see the problem as my `col`s are at size of `sm`.

Here is an image as well showing the embed object spreading outside of the panel.

[image]

Any help appreciated!

*I have also tried searching for ways to make that object to not appear widescreen, but nothing turned up.*

Comment: The latest Bootstrap release (3.2) fixes the embedded scaling issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS property to your object. It will fit inside it's parent container:

```
object {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if you mean that you want your object to fill the entire Panel container, both in width and in height. If it is, I don't think it would be a good idea, the video would stretch and look weird.

Comment: No max-height would not work at all. His current height is defined by his current width, to ensure that the screen ratio is respected

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Responsive Embed classes](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed). For example:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```